# ActionBarSherlock indeterminate progress indicator won't disappear in simulator

Tags: android, progress-bar, actionbarsherlock, android-progressbar

I want my app to be compatible with Android 2.1. On my phone (HTC One X, Android 4+) everything is ok, but in the simulator (2.1), the indeterminate progress bar won't disappear.

I request the feature on creating my activity and start a loading task:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);

    new LoadDataTask().execute();
}
```

In pre- and postExecute of my loading task, the progress bar is shown / hidden:

```
private class LoadDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
    }
}
```

This works fine on my phone, but the simulator will only show the progress bar, never hide it.

Am I using a wrong approach here?

Comment: Have any errors printed in log ?

Comment: add requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS); before super.onCreate(savedInstance);

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the proper ActionBarSherlock method to show and hide the progress.

```
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(visible);
```

instead of

```
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(visible);
```

Comment: Totally missed that one... Mus be because the setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility method does work for showing the progress bar, bot not for hiding it...